# SATA/SSD 2.5'' to USB laptop connection dont show up

Tags: usb, ssd, power-supply, sata

I have several 2.5'' SATA/SSD disks that I want to read in a laptop.

I bought a common SATA/SSD to USB 3.0 adapter but most don't show up and they are silent (no spinning)

I strongly suspect the laptop USB 3.0 adapter is not providing enough power/voltage but all advertisements I see for 2.5" connectors say a power supply is not needed.

What should I do? Buy a power supply as well?

Comment: Is the laptop running on battery or on mains power? Some laptops can only provide full power to USB if they are on mains. And if your laptop has a USB port with a yellow colored inside, try to use that port. Yellow USB ports are usually power-ports that (in many cases) can provide a bit more power than the normal USB ports.

Comment: It is running on main power. No yellow colored port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all USB ports comply with the spec.  The laptop is not supplying enough power.  I too have this issue with an HP Laptop.

You can get a split cable that allows you to supply power via the second cable.  There are warnings around about how this does not comply and may damage things.  So beware.  But some of my USB hard disks came with a split cable, so did my portable monitor.  I havent destroyed anything yet.

SDD is a solid State Disk so there will be no spinning noise.